# Combine Dictionarys in a list based on a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't get my head around this problem:

I have a List:

```
[{'name' : 'Bob', 'Salary2014' : 2000}, {'name': 'Alice', 'Salary2014' : 1000}, {'name':'Bob', 'Salary2013' : 1500}]
```

I want to join the dictionarys on base of the Name (which is unique)

```
[{'name' : 'Bob', 'Salary2014' : 2000, 'Salary2013' : 1500}, {'name': 'Alice', 'Salary2014' : 1000}]
```

I know the solution has to be simple and may involve the .update method, but I just don't get it.

Comment: ...have you actually *tried* using `update`? It the names are unique, why not switch from a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries, keyed by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a new dictionary to track your dictionaries based on name:

```
combined = {}
for d in yourlist:
    combined.setdefault(d['name'], {}).update(d)

output = combined.values()
```

The `combined.setdefault()` method here sets `{}` as a default value if `d['name']` is not present, then updates the dictionary with the current iteration.

If you are using Python 3, use `list(combined.values())`.

Demo:

```
>>> yourlist = [{'name' : 'Bob', 'Salary2014' : 2000}, {'name': 'Alice', 'Salary2014' : 1000}, {'name':'Bob', 'Salary2013' : 1500}]
>>> combined = {}
>>> for d in yourlist:
...     combined.setdefault(d['name'], {}).update(d)
... 
>>> combined.values()
[{'Salary2013': 1500, 'name': 'Bob', 'Salary2014': 2000}, {'name': 'Alice', 'Salary2014': 1000}]
```

Comment: This is a very concise & pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The other pretty similar way is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

inp = [{'name': 'Bob', 'Salary2014': 2000},
       {'name': 'Alice', 'Salary2014': 1000},
       {'name': 'Bob', 'Salary2013': 1500}]

out = defaultdict(dict)

for rec in inp:
    out[rec['name']].update(rec)

print out.values()
```